# rewrite lighthttpd QSA

Tags: regex, apache, url-rewriting, lighttpd

Help rewrite flag apache - QSA for lighttpd.
Now available:

```
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L, QSA]
```

Try the case, but is not functioning properly:

```
url.rewrite-if-not-file = ("^/(?:\?(.*))?" => "/index.php?_route_=$1")
```

Comment: Not functioning properly how?  What is it doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand of lighttpd:

```
url.rewrite-if-not-file = ("^/([^\?]*)$" => "/index.php?_route_=$1")
```

.. should work.  If not, then the following will:

```
url.rewrite-if-not-file = ("^([^\?]*)$" => "/index.php?_route_=$1")
```

Comment: This version does not work. If the URL is present in a question mark, I get a 404 page

Comment: `^([^\?]+)[\?]{0,1}(.*)$` and $1 would relate to the file, ie `index.php` and $2 would relate to the query, ie `index.php?myvar=test` it would match the `myvar=test` part.

Comment: (I am assuming you already tried `^(.*)$` to match everything inputed... )

Comment: yes, this is the first thing I tried. In this case, $ _GET when requested, for example:

http://host.com/tea/white_tea/?sort=pd.name&order=ASC

$ _GET Contains:

["_route_"] => "tea / white_tea /? sort = pd.name"
["order"] => "ASC"

While it is expected:

["_route_"] => "tea / white_tea /"
["sort"] => "pd.name"
["order"] => "ASC"

Comment: Then try... `url.rewrite-if-not-file = ("^([^\?]+)[\?]{0,1}(.*)$" => "/index.php?route=$1&$2"`

Comment: Now, if you ask, for example:

[link](http://chinachay.rework.pro/tea/white_tea/?sort=pd.name&order=ASC)

I redirect (301) to

[link](http://chinachay.rework.pro/index.php?route=/tea/white_tea/&sort=pd.name&order=ASC)

See for yourself the related links.

Comment: I can't really read the page...but from what I can tell...it seems to be working? `http://chinachay.rework.pro/tea/black_tea/&sort=pd.name&order=ASC` does a redirect correctly.

Comment: Thank you! Understood. Just in case your minor typo, do this:

`(url.rewrite-if-not-file = ("^([^\?]+)[\?]{0,1}(.*)$" => "/index.php?_route_=$1&$2")`

Comment: Ahh, yes the `_route_`, I had removed the underscores because you said `While it is expected: ["route"] => "tea / white_tea /" ["sort"] => "pd.name" ["order"] => "ASC"` so I assumed you wanted the underscores gone. :)  But add them back if needed, and it should work as you want ^^

Comment: When your questions are answered, don't forget to mark them as 'accepted'. ^^  I noticed you haven't done that with any questions you've asked.  Just letting you know that's the best accepted practice. ^^